# Adding to a List of objects from the View

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, razor

What I wanted to do was seeming simple but I am having a bit of trouble. I've created the following class:

```
// SelectedItem.cs
public class SelectedItem
{
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

In my view page I've created a list of SelectedItem:

```
// Chart.cshtml
@model Prediction.Models.Chart.ManualSelection
@{
    @using Prediction.Models.Chart
     List<SelectedItem> selectedItems = new List<SelectedItem>();
}
```

And I'm trying to add to this list from the html in my view. I've created a table that has its rows populated by a foreach loop.

```
// Also Chart.cshtml, below the previous code section where I created the list
<table class="table table-borderless table-hover table-striped table-sm mb-0">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.PhoneInfo)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Brand)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Select</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is when the button is clicked, I want that specific `item.Brand` and `item.Model` to be added to `List<SelectedItem> selectedItems`.

Comment: Your list only exists when the view is rendered on the server-side. Anything that happens, such as a button click, after the page is rendered happens on the client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is impossible. Like it was mentioned in the comment, this `list` exists only in the scope of rendering view on the server, before sending to the client's browser. In order to save your `item.Brand` and `item.Model` you need to use `JavaScript`, that will be executed in browser on client side or you can send this information back to the server and process it there.